# iSCSI HDD (ext4) from Windows10 to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, iscsi

I have a 1TB HDD [ext4] connected to a Windows 10 PC and would like to connect this HDD in RAW mode to access it from a Linux computer over LAN to mount it from there.

- The problem on Win10 is when I tried to use *ISCSI Initiator* it asks me to use a mounted unit, however you cannot mount an ext4 on Windows

How can I do this?

Comment: First of all, what you want to do is to create a iscsi *target* intead of initiator on a physical drive (or maybe just a "not-volume" partition). However it seems that Windows does not (at least not itself) provide such feature (which fits with the Microsoft/Windows-style though, since every recognized filesystem will be mounted automatically as a volume by default, which is something needs to be avoided for this kind of "passthrough" iSCSI setup, and that Microsoft never really expects you to use Windows for something non-Windows (apart from the WSes gimmicks for making the OS look "trendy").

Comment: and how could I do? Thanks

Comment: nobody knows if it is possible to do this?

Comment: @vincenzogianfelice You can mount ext2/3/4, Btrfs, and XFS filesystems on Windows via Paragon's [LinuxFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/) _(read is supported from the free edition, r/w requires a license - ext2/3/4 has been supported on Windows for ~10yrs)_

Answer (score 0):

MS iSCSI Target can't share physical drives, you need to create VHD, which will be shared via iSCSI:

- You can use [StarWind Virtual SAN](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/help/PhysicalHardDrives.html) to share your drive via iSCSI amd a [lio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ISCSI/LIO) target on Linux.

Comment: Please use correct markdown for weblinks _(see formatting bar)_

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will follow the markdowns.

Comment: Thanks! is there anything open source? Or could you tell me where I can download this software? Because I have to register, enter the phone number, etc .. but I don't have a company